# SVG <image> and nested <svg> elements are different sizes, even with equal width and height attributes

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

I created an svg in Inkscape which contains references to other svgs that I want to interact with via JS.  Inkscape seems to only be able to embed them as `<image>` so I can't interact with elements inside of them directly.

My solution is to replace the `<image>` elements with corresponding inline `<svg>` elements so that I can manipulate their contents from JS.  This seems to work, except that the `<svg>` elements are sized differently than the `<image>` elements they replace.

Here's the code I'm using to do the replacement.  I'm trying to copy over the position, size and ID from the `<image>` to the `<svg>`

```js
//Inkscape apparently won't make a <svg> reference for me, but uses an <image> element as a link
//This function replaces the <image> with a <svg> element
function imageToUse(imageNode) {
    //using webpack.  src will be the contents of the embedded svg as a string
    let src = imageToUseMap[imageNode.getAttribute("xlink:href")];
    //parse the svg to get a doc fragment
    let scFrag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(src);
    let scElement = scFrag.firstElementChild;

    //copy size and positioning data
    let toCopy = ["x", "y", "width", "height", "id"];
    for (let attr of toCopy) {
        scElement.setAttribute(attr, imageNode.getAttributeNS(null, attr));
    }
    //and replace
    let parent = imageNode.parentNode;
    imageNode.remove();
    parent.appendChild(scElement);

    return scElement;
```

Are there other attributes of the `<image>` that I should be copying over?  Am I using incorrect methods (setAttribute vs setAttributeNS or something?)?  Are there other differences between rendering an `<image>` vs a nested inline`<svg>` element?

Before the JS replaces the `<image>` elements with corresponding `<svg>`
[image: Before]

After (I'm also changing some textContent, I assume that isn't effecting the SVG sizes):
[image]

Note, the 2 stacked boxes on the left are embedded SVGs that I replace, and they behave as expected.  The two "sliders" to the right seem to have incorrect y/height values.

I read that a `<use>` element might be a good choice for the embedded images as well.  It may not be possible to manipulate the internal elements because of the shadow boundary, though, right?

Comment: "src will be the contents of the embedded svg as a string" what does that mean concretely? I fail to see how can the `href` be raw markup? It needs to be an URI of some sort. And you probably miss some viewBox from the root svg, but why do you even go through the pain of cloning the element there? Can't you simply append that parsed element directly?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, I'm sorry.  I intended to try to get Inkscape to emit a `<use>` element, but I'm actually creating a nested SVG element.  I should try making an actual `<use>` element and copying over the href... Thanks for catching that.  Src comes from a webpack "source asset" so it's literally the text content of the svg file ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
```...

Comment: I guess I'll edit the question, to ask about why a nested SVG is the wrong size compared to an <image> that should have exactly the same contents

Comment: Can you try to create a [MCVE]? (e.g with just a green rectangle as target svg)

Comment: Here's a fairly reduced version of the project: https://github.com/benjones/svgResizingReduced.  The nested SVGs each just contain 1 rectangle now.  The behavior is the same as the pictures above except that only the containing rectangles exist